# How i can convert the following sql query to HQL query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I have the following query.How i can convert the following query to HQL query.

```
+--------+------------+-------+
| type   | variety    | price |
+--------+------------+-------+
| apple  | gala       |  2.79 | 
| apple  | fuji       |  0.24 | 
| apple  | limbertwig |  2.87 | 
| orange | valencia   |  3.59 | 
| orange | navel      |  9.36 | 
| pear   | bradford   |  6.05 | 
| pear   | bartlett   |  2.14 | 
| cherry | bing       |  2.55 | 
| cherry | chelan     |  6.33 | 
+--------+------------+-------+
```

I want to get the following result

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| type   | variety  | price |
+--------+----------+-------+
| apple  | fuji     |  0.24 | 
| orange | valencia |  3.59 | 
| pear   | bartlett |  2.14 | 
| cherry | bing     |  2.55 | 
+--------+----------+-------+

 select f.type, f.variety, f.price
from (
   select type, min(price) as minprice
   from fruits group by type
) as x inner join fruits as f on f.type = x.type and f.price = x.minprice;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work (not tested):

```
select f.type, f.variety, f.price
from fruits f
where f.price = (
  select min(f2.price)
  from fruits f2
  where f2.type = f.type
)
```

**EDIT**: Keep in mind that if a `type` has the same `price` for more than one `variety`, than all of those rows will be selected with this query.

Comment: can i write this using joins

Comment: From the documentation: *HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses* http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

Comment: but it is giving all the records for me.I need only the top record only

Comment: Do you want only this row?:  `apple  | fuji     |  0.24`

Comment: Well, i made a sample project and it is producing the desired result with the sample data provided. Maybe there is problem somewhere else? Also, i added a note to my answer.